# how to get clean raw data from a firestore document?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When handling Firestore triggers in Google Cloud Functions as in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#code_sample), the provided data object has some extra value fields that are not in the source data such as stringValue, arrayValue, mapValue etc (see example below). I am not interested in these and I'd like to get the raw data instead. is that feasible?

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT,
});

// Converts strings added to /messages/{pushId}/original to uppercase
exports.makeUpperCase = event => {
  const resource = event.value.name;
  const affectedDoc = firestore.doc(resource.split('/documents/')[1]);

  const curValue = event.value.fields.original.stringValue;
  const newValue = curValue.toUpperCase();

  if (curValue !== newValue) {
    console.log(`Replacing value: ${curValue} --> ${newValue}`);

    return affectedDoc.set({
      original: newValue,
    });
  } else {
    // Value is already upper-case
    // Don't perform a(nother) write to avoid infinite loops
    console.log('Value is already upper-case.');
  }
};
```

with a response similar to

```
{
  "fields": {
    "original": {
      "stringValue": "1va7531b-f7bf-42d0-930f-f16153089f12"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you get this data. I assume it may be coming from the REST API, but your question should make that clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure about that data format, but I must admit that I only consume Firestore data in Cloud Functions for Firebase, which may affect what you get. I hope somebody else knows the answer.